# Post an uploaded file from flask to an API

Tags: python, api, flask

I've build a small flask application with a file input form, and now I want that file to be sent to an API.

```
@app.route('/test', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def test():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        file = request.files['file']
        file.save(secure_filename(file.filename))
```

My Layout for the post part:

```
    data = {
        "local": file, 
        "name": file.filename
    }

    rp = requests.post(f'https://www.meistertask.com/api/tasks/{task_id}/attachments', data, headers={'Authorization': f'Bearer {access_token}'})
    print(rp.status_code)
    print(rp.content)
```

No matter how I try to post that file to the API, I always get this response:

```
{
    "errors": [
        {
            "message": "Parameter local should be of type ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile!",
            "status": 400
        }
    ]
}
```

I really don't know how to post a file of that type from my uploaded file in flask.
I'd really appreciate any help! Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Please add both the API specifications and the code you used to post to it.

Comment: API doc: https://developers.meistertask.com/docs/post-attachment
I added my post part. I tried so much different things...

Answer (score 0):

`file` is not a real file, but a filestorage from the werkzeug package.

https://werkzeug.palletsprojects.com/en/1.0.x/datastructures/#werkzeug.datastructures.FileStorage

The API documentation of meistertask is not clear to me, especially I cannot see what `local` should be. A path? A stream? Bytes?

Comment: yeah, exactly thats my problem... At first I just tried a random String as local, and also got this error:
"Parameter local should be of type ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile!"
I really don't know that type, or how to handle this with Python.

Answer (score 0):

I got it working with python urlib... maybe this helps you

```
f = open(fname,'rb')
content = f.read()
f.close()
    

url = 'https://www.meistertask.com/api/tasks/%s/attachments' % (task_id)
request = urllib.request.Request("%s" %(url))
boundary = "5645645645654"
request.add_header("User-Agent", "python-test")
request.add_header("Accept", "*/*")
request.add_header("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate")
request.add_header("Content-Type","multipart/form-data; boundary=%s" % boundary)
request.add_header("Connection", "keep-alive")
request.add_header("Expect", "100-continue")
request.add_header("Authorization", "Bearer 11111111111111111111")

body = bytes("--%s\r\n" % boundary,'utf-8')  
body += bytes('Content-Disposition: form-data; name="name"\r\n\r\n','utf-8')
body += bytes('%s\r\n' % fname,'utf-8')

body += bytes("--%s\r\n" % boundary,'utf-8')
body += bytes('Content-Disposition: file; name="local"; filename="%s"\r\n' % fname,'utf-8')
body += bytes('Content-Type: text/plain\r\n\r\n','utf-8')
body += content
body += bytes('\r\n','utf-8')

body += bytes("\r\n--%s--\r\n" % boundary,'utf-8')
request.data = body
#print(body)
f = urllib.request.urlopen(request)
response = f.read() #bytes
```

Comment: Please use the answer section _for answers only_. If you have a similar question then start a new one (and link to this one here, if useful).